# 自分で定義したtemplate <class Iter>のIterの中に型名が存在している理由がわかりませんでした。

Tags: c++

以下のような実装がiterator_traits構造体の実装として書かれていましたが、
なぜ、Iterクラスの名前空間内にdifference_typeやvalue_typeのような型があるのでしょうか。
僕の考えだと、template としたとき、Iterが表すのは、templateの型名でしかないという認識だったのですが、その自分がtemplateとして定義したIterの中に、difference_typeなどの型があるのか不思議です。
わかるかた教えていただけると助かります。

````
            struct iterator_traits {
                typedef typename Iter::difference_type difference_type;
                typedef typename Iter::value_type value_type;
                typedef typename Iter::pointer pointer;
                typedef typename Iter::reference reference;
                typedef typename Iter::iterator_category iterator_category;
                /*
                 * difference_type  イテレータの減算演算時の型
                 * value_type   イテレータの指す値型
                 * pointer  イテレータのポインタ型
                 * reference    イテレータの参照型
                 * iterator_category    イテレータのカテゴリ型
                 */
            };```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> なぜ、Iterクラスの名前空間内にdifference_typeやvalue_typeのような型があるのでしょうか。

考え方が逆です。

テンプレートパラメータ`Iter`がC++標準ライブラリの「イテレータ(iterator)」互換であれば、`Iter::difference_type`や`Iter::value_type`といった型名が提供されます。これらの型名を提供しないクラスは、C++イテレータと呼べないと言い換えても良いでしょう。

※注：例外事項として言語組込のポインタ(pointer)型に対してのみ [`iterator_traits<T*>`のようなテンプレート特殊化](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iterator/iterator_traits.html) が行われます。[Akira Takahashiさん回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/93006/)も参照ください。

---

> Iterが表すのは、templateの型名でしかないという認識だったのですが、

ここまでは、正しい認識です。

> その自分がtemplateとして定義したIterの中に、difference_typeなどの型があるのか不思議です。

前述の通り、C++におけるイテレータクラスは`difference_type`などの型を提供しなければなりません。標準ライブラリ提供コンテナのイテレータは、全てのこの要請に従ったクラスとして実装されます。

仮にあなた自身がテンプレートパラメータ`Iter`に渡す「イテレータ」クラスを実装するのであれば、C++標準ライブラリ仕様が要求する外部インタフェース仕様に従わなければなりません。

Comment: なるほど！とても納得のいく説明でした！ありがとうございます！
iteratorを表現するテンプレートとして定義するためにdifference_typeなどの型を提供するようにしていたのですね！

Answer (score 2):

`iterator_traits`にはポインタに対する特殊化が定義されています。

```
template<class T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
  typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef T* pointer;
  typedef T& reference;
  typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};
```

組み込みのポインタ型は直接的に`difference_type`を持っていないので、この`iterator_traits`とポインタに対する特殊化があることによって、コンテナ型がもつイテレータ型と、組み込みのポインタ型を共通して使えるようになります。

```
typedef iterator_traits<vector<int>::iterator>::difference_type a;
typedef iterator_traits<int*>::difference_type b;
```

Answer (score 0):

実体の分からない型`Iter`を使って何か処理をするテンプレートクラスや関数テンプレートを定義するのに必要になります。
例えば以下のページで合計値を計算する`sum`関数テンプレートを定義していますが、イテレータ`Iterator`が指している値型`value_type`（`int`かもしれないし、`double`かもしれないし、その他かもしれないし）が提供されないと、合計値を格納する変数`result`や戻り値の型を決められないため処理を書けません。

https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iterator/iterator_traits.html

```
// 範囲の合計値を計算する
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
    sum(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
  // イテレータの型から値型を取得する
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

  // 取得した値型の変数を定義し、合計値を計算する
  value_type result = value_type();
  for (; first != last; ++first) {
    result += *first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
 template型の存在意義はわかっているつもりなのですが、そのtemplate型として定義された変数を使って、記述する typedef typename Iter::difference_type difference_type;の意味がわからないというのが疑問です。。

Comment: 疑問点が良く分かりませんが、[前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92990/c%e3%81%aestl%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%86%e3%83%8a%e5%86%85%e3%81%a7typedef%e3%82%92%e5%a4%9a%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-member-types%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9a%e7%be%a9%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b)と同様に、`Iter::difference_type`を直接使わずになぜ`std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type`に定義し直しているのかということでしょうか？